# double backslash while take input

Tags: python, input, backslash

i just finished learning python
so i try to build my first project which is backup tool but from many dir so the problem as always with me in windows path and backslash
here is the code

```
import os
def list():
    AO = True
    while AO:
        list_files = []
        user_input = input("please put path of the file : ")
        list_files.append(user_input)
```

so when i try to print the list i get path with double backslash so is there any way to get input as raw string

Comment: Please, fix typo's and use a code block..

Comment: Don't worry about the doubled backslashes, that's just the string representation, which is what you see when you print a list of strings. The paths will be correct. However, you have a logic error: you need to put `list_files = []` _before_ the start of the `while` loop.

Comment: not duplicate as i saw this before but it works when you give it as var without user input

Comment: yes i know i have to put list_files out the while loop or it will enter the loop with it and have new list every time thanks i hope it works